# Io - List Shuffling

Tags: iolanguage

I tried to shuffle a list in Io:

```
list(1, 2, 3, 4) shuffle println
```

However, when I tried to run the program, Io gave me an error:

```
  Exception: List does not respond to 'shuffle'
  ---------
  List shuffle                         .code.tio 1
  CLI doFile                           Z_CLI.io 140
  CLI run                              IoState_runCLI() 1
```

Is there an alternative for shuffling in Io? If not, how do I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you need to load the Random addon, which will add the List shuffle method.